# Django db_index issue

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, indexing

Currently, I have 3 models, A, B and C

C has foreign key to B
B has foreign key to A

```
class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, unique=True)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
class B:
...similar to C
class A
...similar to C except for the FK
```

However, the SQL generated by manage.py sqlindexes app doesn't create indexes for C.name, B.name, and A.name. Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to me like it'll be because the fields also have `unique = True`, so I wouldn't worry too much about it. If you've got `unique = True`, then you'll get a unique index (which may or may not be implemented as a database index), so I guess Django just ignores the `db_index = True` bit.

I get very similar behaviour for one of my models that is similarly specified. What output do you get when run `manage.py sql app`? Do you see the `name` fields being created with `UNIQUE`?

Comment: Hmm I just ran sqlindexes on the app again and it generated indexes for name. Donno what happened in the OP lol